# Find all the subexpressions with a given head in an expression

Tags: function-construction, expression-manipulation

Given an arbitrary mathematical expression `expr` involving summations and multiplications I would like to find all unique instances of subexpressions  with a specified head, e.g., the head `h`. I hacked together a solution as follows:

```
findAll[expr_, h_] := 
  Cases[expr /. Times -> list1 /. Plus -> list2 /. h[x__] :> (h[x] /. list2 -> Plus /. list1 -> Times) /. list1 -> List /. list2 -> List /. Power -> List // Flatten, h[__]] // DeleteDuplicates
```

but I'm afraid my code is ignoring some advanced functionality that might be present in Mathematica and could return a result much quicker. What would be an efficient way to write my code?

Example:

```
expr = (a + b h[1])/(h[2] + c) + h[3];
findAll[expr, h]
```

> `{h[3], h[1], h[2]}`

Comment: `DeleteDuplicates@Cases[expr, _h, Infinity]`?

Comment: @kglr wow, thanks! This seems to be it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
DeleteDuplicates @ Cases[expr, _h, Infinity]
```

> {h[1], h[2], h[3]}

```
ClearAll[findAll]
findAll = DeleteDuplicates @ Cases[#, Blank[#2], Infinity] &;

findAll[expr, h]
```

> {h[1], h[2], h[3]}

Comment: Sorry to ask for more details, but what if I'm interested in finding symbols with several heads in one go, how should I do that properly? I tried `DeleteDuplicates @ Cases[expr, _h1||_h2, Infinity]`, but it does not work.

Comment: @Kagaratsch, use `Alternatives` instead of `Or`, i.e., try `DeleteDuplicates @ Cases[expr, _h1 | _h2, Infinity]`

Comment: I see, thank you again!

Comment: @Kagaratsch, my pleasure. Thank you for the accept.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed question, but what if I'd like to find all instances of `h[x][y]` instead of `h[x]`, which pattern should I be using in that case? The pattern `_h` does not work in that case, unfortunately.

Comment: @Kagaratsch, try the pattern `_h[_]`?

Comment: Awesome, thank you again!